# Get longest List-Title name in Sharepoint-Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want to get the longest list-title name, how do I do this?

I thought this would work:

```
    function onSuccess() {

    var listString;
    var listEnumerator = listCollection.getEnumerator();

    var longest = "";

    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current(),
            title = currentItem.get_title();

        listString += "<br>" + title;

        if (longest.length > title.length)
            longest = title;
    }
    $('#AllLists').html(longest);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change **greater than** to **less than** in this line:

```
if (longest.length > title.length)
```

change to:

```
if (longest.length < title.length)
```